# Series solution to an ODE always giving me 0

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

I have the ODE

$$y''-9x^4y=0,$$
and I want a series solution of the form
$$y(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}x}e^{x^3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^{n\alpha}$$
for some constant $\alpha$.

Through all my attempts, I get $\alpha=3$ and
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 18 na_nx^{3n}+\sum_{n=-1}^\infty (3n+2)(3n+1)a_{n+1}x^{3n}=0.$$
However, this immediately tells me $a_0=0$ and
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{18n}{(3n+2)(3n+1)}a_n$$
so the whole series is 0. I know this is wrong because I know the solution is supposed to be
$$\sqrt{2\pi x}I_\frac{1}{6}(x^3),$$
where $I_\nu(x)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind. Can anyone tell me where the hole in my thinking is? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you got the formula for the sum wrong. If I plug in your series with $\alpha=3$, I get terms with $x^{3n+1}$, $x^{3n-2}$, and $x^{3n+3}$. If you change the limits to have the same power of $x$, you should get a recursion formula with three values of $a$ instead of two.

Comment: Could you share your formula for the sum? I've tried multiple attempts and have always been arriving to the same thing.

Comment: I have a small mistake. I just took the first derivative. I've pasted the formula below.

Answer (score 1):

$$y''=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\frac{x^{3n-3}\left(9x^6+18nx^3+9n^2-9n+2\right)\mathrm{e}^{x^3}}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Answer (score 0):

While the factor $x^{-1}$ is part of the asymptotic formula for $y''-Qy=0$, $Q>0$, at large $x$
$$
y(x)\sim Q(x)^{-\frac14}\exp\left(\pm\int\sqrt{Q(x)}dx\right),
$$
the power series expansion is valid for $x\approx 0$. As the equation is not singular, it makes no sense to include it in the factorization. Thus set
$$
y(x)=e^{x^3}u(x)\implies y'(x)=e^{x^3}\left(u'(x)+3x^2u(x)\right)\\
\implies y''(x)=e^{x^3}\left(u''(x)+6x^2u'(x)+(6x+9x^2)u(x)\right)
$$
which gives the differential equation for the factor $u$
$$
u''(x)+6x^2u'(x)+6xu(x)=0.
$$
With the power series expansion $u(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ we get the coefficient equations for $x^n$ (with the understanding that $a_n=0$ for $n<0$)
$$
(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}+6(n-1)a_{n-1}+6a_{n-1}=0
$$
Thus only the coefficients for $n=3m$ are not automatically zero and 
$$
a_{3m+3}=-\frac{6(3m+1)}{(3m+3)(3m+2)}a_{3m}.
$$

---

In short, your problem was that you only had the coefficients for $n=3m-1$ in your series, which are automatically zero. You would have needed to include a "phase shift" $r$ in the exponent,
$$
y(x)=\frac{e^{x^3}}{\sqrt3x}\sum a_nx^{n\alpha+r}.
$$